# Can blocking still cause thread starvation?

Tags: java, concurrency

This may be a remedial question, but I just had a double-take and I need to clarify something. If I have a fixed thread pool that manages 5 threads, and I have 150 instances of Task A and 150 instances of Task B... and task B is dependent on its Task A counterpart's completion, and thus it can block waiting for Task A. And tasks of both A and B are submitted to the same fixed threadpool, that can cause thread starvation correct? When one task blocks, it does not free that thread to execute another task. Right?

Comment: If task B can block the threads while waiting on task A, then yes, it can cause starvation. There are many ways to fix this, but one of the easiest is to not allow task B to block if it's counterpart hasn't executed yet. Hard to say exactly without seeing some code though, but generally that should be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume so, although I'm having a hard time finding any information about it. It would make little sense to implement preemptive multitasking in Java. For me as a developer it is safer to assume that a single thread runs only one task until its completion, than that several tasks can share a thread at the same time.

Create two separate executors: one for tasks A, another for B.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm thinking too... I'm not a low-level programmer by any means but it would seem messy for a thread to jump from one uncompleted task to another I imagine.

Comment: And yeah I'm going to take the dual executor strategy too.

Comment: When dealing with blocking strategies and shared resources, order very much matters :)

Comment: @DylanMeeus I think priority only affects which task will get to be executed on a next available thread first. It does not mean that java would interrupt other tasks to run a task with higher priority.

Comment: For now I just went ahead and used some synchronized lazy initialization between Task A and Task B, which overcomes the complex dependencies they have with each other, and I called the lazy methods as runnable tasks to get some asynchronous gains. I'll look at dividing the threadpools later.

Comment: Sounds good to me. This looks like a producer consumer problem. I would expect tasks A to write results to synchronized queue and another task spawning new tasks B as more data becomes available.